# Rearrange a list in Python when new value is added or removed

Tags: python, sorting

I would like to know if there is an efficient way to sort a list of numbers without repeating any of them and that by modifying any element the rest are reordered.

e.g.

`list = [1,2,3,4]`

Case 1: If I add to the list another number 2, the number 2 from the list and next one should be pushed to next value.
`[1,2,3,4] <- new 2 [1,2,3("old" 2),4("old" 3),5("old" 4)]`

Same if I delete one number in any position.

Case 1: I modify the number 4 to be a 2, the list must-> the "old" 2 should convert into 3 and the "old" into 4 like moving/pushing numbers.

to sumary, some efficient way to insert a number and this number will take the position of his value, moving the other back or forward.

I hope this is clear.

**EDIT to clarify**

the numbers are related to something. products in this case but it doesnt matter right now.
so:

```py
product1: have this value 1 produc1{id: 1}
product2: have this value 2 produc2{id: 2}
product3: have this value 3 produc3{id: 3}
product4: have this value 4 produc4{id: 4}
```

so in case I want to change order i want to modify for example product4 to be in produc's 2 position.

```py
product1: have this value 1 produc1{id: 1}
product2: have this value 2 produc2{id: 2}
product3: have this value 3 produc3{id: 3}
product4: have this value 4 produc4{id: 4}  # I change this 4 for a 2
```

then it should be sorted by id

```py
product1: have this value 1 produc1{id: 1}
product4: have this value 2 produc4{id: 2} # this was a 4 modified to 2 (manualy)
product2: have this value 3 produc2{id: 3} # this was a 2 converted to 3
product3: have this value 4 produc3{id: 4} # this was a 3 converted to 4
```

Another case

```py
product1: have this value 1 produc1{id: 1}
product2: have this value 2 produc2{id: 2}  # delete this product2
product3: have this value 3 produc3{id: 3}
product4: have this value 4 produc4{id: 4}
```

then:

```py
product1: have this value 1 produc1{id: 1}
product2: have this value 2 produc3{id: 2}  # this id was 3 
product3: have this value 3 produc4{id: 3}  # this id was 4
```

About getting a out of index number I will stop it somehow, but not interested on that right now.

I hope this is clear now.

Comment: What would be desirable behaviour in the case that a non-sequential value is added to your `list`? e.g. if you wanted to add the value `7` to `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you expect, can you simply show your actual expected output, without confusing `("old" ...)` annotations? It sounds like you simply always want a list of 1 to *n*? If you have a list of `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, then whatever you insert, you get `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`? How's that different from just having a variable `n = 5`?

Comment: I'm simply reading: you always want to have a list from 1 to *n*. Like… what changed in your "I change this 4 for a 2" example? Nothing. It's a list of products 1..4. If you have a bunch of objects in a list, why not simply use the list index as numeric id, or whatever you're attempting to do?

Answer (score -2):

See below - using [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html)

```
import bisect 
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
bisect.insort(lst, 3) 
print(lst)
```

Comment: That repeats `3`.